# Нарушаю ли авторские права?

Tags: google-play, мобильные-приложения, авторские-права

У меня есть приложение в Google Play - агрегатор новостей определенной узкой тематики с разных сайтов. Приложение ничего не хранит, просто выводит пользователю информацию в удобном виде. С недавнего времени поступают угрозы "забанить в гугле" от владельца одного из сайтов-источников. Нарушает ли данное приложение авторские права владельцев сайтов с точки зрения Google и стоит ли мне переписать приложение во избежание проблем? Видел множество подобных успешно и уже давно живущих программ.

Comment: С тем же успехом можно забанить программы браузеры - они же позволяют лазить на эти сайты источники напрямую ))))
Если правильно написать DISCLAIMER, то никакие авторские права владельцев сайтов не пострадают....

Comment: Согласен с @gecube. Технически ваше приложение - просто браузер для определенных сайтов, который рендерит контент по-своему.

Comment: Технически это приложение — парсер и воришка, потому что вместо установленных авторами дизайна, счётчиков, рекламы и прочего приложение выводит что хочет и как хочет

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это юридический вопрос, не имеющий непосредственного отношения к программированию.

Comment: @Nofate, задавая этот вопрос именно здесь, я специально акцентировал внимание на фразе "с точки зрения Google". Т.е. интересует меня в первую очередь опыт программистов под Android, которые уже имеют опыт подобных конфликтов с Google. Сухое мнение юристов мне тут врядли поможет.

Comment: @Pavel, по-моему, логичнее обратиться в техподдержку Google, чем полагаться на субъективные мнения.

Comment: @Nofate, они отвечают ни к чему не обязывающими шаблонами на любой такой вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае жалобы правообладателя, никто не будет ничего доказывать вам или им. Это потому, что Google не хочет проблем, связанных с авторскими правами на свою голову. Ваше приложение будет удалено сразу. Блоки `AdMob` тоже будут удалены через какое-то время. Сам столкнулся.

Comment: Этот ответ оказался ближе всех. Приложение забанили, причем, судя по датам, без особых заморочек с проверками реальности наличия какого-либо нарушения.

Answer (score 2):

Если они докажут, что новости ты тянешь с их сайта, а их новости уникальные, то да.

Answer (score 2):

Ссылки на оригинальные источники есть? Если да - то Вам ничего не грозит. Но если не идти в конфликт с другими людьми - то надо просто исключить этот источник в агрегаторе.

Answer (score 2):

По своему опыту скажу, что главное в названии не использовать и не упоминать каким-либо образом чужие имена. Бан последует и google разбираться не станет. По крайней мере, со мной такое произошло.